# Continuations (Async Web Services) in Spring 15 Sandbox

Tags: apex, webservices, asynchronous, pre-release

According to Spring 15 release notes, Continuations class should be available in Spring 15.  I have a preview Sandbox (on CS21) but this feature does not appear to be enabled as the Apex does not compile when referencing the Continuations class.  Do I have to do anything to enable the feature?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was about a release over a year past, and still does not have an accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Asynchronous Callouts feature is still in Pilot, scheduled to end on 2/13/15, which is when R2 of 194 rolls out. Perhaps that is why you are getting this error.

Comment: OK thank you - so is it still scheduled for GA in Spring 15?